# Best practise to read data as XML from an XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, spring-jdbc

Am currently rendering stuff from a web service using XSLT. I would like to edit data from XSLT and send it as an XML to Java.

I can get the data and save it as an XML file from XSLT but would like to send the XML response directly to Java or Spring. I would like to edit the item description and then send the response to webservice as XML

Is there any best practise or approach to perform the above task ?

Here is the sample code of my current XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
                xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>                
                <title>My Title</title>         
            </head>
            <body>
                <section>                    
                    <xsl:call-template name="Update-template"/>
                </section>                
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Update-template">
        <table class="myClass">
           <xsl:for-each select="/MyWs/Info">            
                <xsl:for-each select="item">                                               
                    <tr>                        
                        <th>Item No</th>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:value-of select="itemNo"/>
                        </td>                                                                   
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Description</th>                       
                        <td>                           
                            <textarea name = "itemDesc"> 
                                <xsl:value-of select="itemDesc"/>
                            </textarea> 
                        </td>                                               
                    </tr>      
                </xsl:for-each>      
           </xsl:for-each>
       </table>
    </xsl:template> 
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As far as I know the entire XSLT api works with (amongst other things) streams. Use ByteArrayOutputStream if you want to output to memory?

Comment: Well, am using text boxes in XSLT and reading data from that boxes. So, have to grab it and send to Spring.

Comment: Need more information, show some code.

Comment: When you say you are 'currently rendering stuff from a web service using XSLT' - do you mean that you are manually (saving from a browser?) downloading XML from a WebService and saving to a file ? I'm not quite sure I understand your question - but maybe you need to look at running the XSLT transform from your own Java Program directly (as opposed to running (say) a 'transform' commandline)?

Comment: No, am not saving manually to an xml file. Webservice will forward the response in XML format. Am using that response to render them using the above XSLT

Comment: As others have said: The TrAX API can output to streams, or can produce SAX events or a DOM tree if you want a parsed view of the data. Just a matter of setting up the right result handler in your code before running the XSLT. Which are you looking for?